# Roots of a polynomial equation where coefficients follow a geometric progression

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, polynomials, roots

Given a positive constant $a\in\mathbb{R}$, , and a positive integer $n$, I am interested in the roots of $x^n + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a^i x^{n-i-1} = x^n + x^{n-1} + a x^{n-2} + a^2 x^{n-3} +\cdots + a^{n-1}= 0$. Images of the roots in the complex plane for a few select values of $n$ and $a$ are below. **Is there analytical formula for these roots?**

[image]

This problem is equivalent to finding the eigenvalues of the $n\times n$ Hessenberg matrix:
$\left(\begin{matrix} -1& -1 & -1 & \cdots&-1 \\ a & 0  & 0& \cdots & 0 \\ 0 & a & 0 & \cdots &0 \\ \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & \cdots & 0 & a &0   \end{matrix}\right)$

The geometric structure of the roots in the images makes me think there should be a clean analytic solution here, but I'm having difficulty to find one.

Note: Ultimately, I am trying to show that for $0<a<1$, the eigenvalues $\lambda$ of the following matrix satisfy $|\lambda|<1$. Numerically, I have found this to be true. Any ideas here would be appreciated as well.

$\left(\begin{matrix} -a& -1 & -1 & \cdots&-1 \\ 
a & 1-a  & 0& \cdots & 0 \\ 
0 & a & 1-a & \ddots & \vdots \\ 
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\ 
0 & \cdots & 0 & a &1-a   \end{matrix}\right)$

Comment: Your first formula does not agree. Summing up $i$ from $0$ to $n-1$ yields another $x^n$.

Comment: Updated, thanks!

Comment: Multiplying by $x-a$ shows that it's equivalent to understand the roots of $x^{n+1} + (1-a)x^n -a^n$.

Comment: Based on the formula given by Greg Martin one would expect that the roots settle down to the circle $|x| = |a|$ as $n \to \infty$.